# Why does my Google devtools CSS editor blink?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

So basically my problem is that my Chrome dev tools CSS editor **blinks** when I'm editing Wordpress child theme, I was wondering if there is some kind of autosaving on which shouldn't be possible because Chrome can't save straight to my server without any settings. This problem is not happening with any other CSS files, but when I start editing child theme file in the editor it starts blinking. I didn't find out any solutions when Googling this problem so maybe you guys can help me with this problem.

**You can see my problem here**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your CSS file is using `@import url(...);` somewhere.

Try to remove `@import` on your CSS file you editing, And no blinking anyway.

**PS : [Don't use @import](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/)**